# How should I club android permission for camera and external storage

Tags: android, android-permissions

I had two permission in my application and they are based on accessing **camera** and **external storage** but problem I am facing is that only camera permission is asked when application launches and other permission are is not asked.

But in second phase when I run application it asked second permission.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private NavigationView nvDrawer;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0;
private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;

private static String[] PERMISSION_EXTERNAL = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }
    } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    PERMISSION_EXTERNAL, REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
    mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);
    drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();
    mDrawer.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //granted
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }
    } else if (requestCode != REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) {
        if (PermissionUtil.verifyPermission(grantResults)) {
            //Has been granted
        } else {
            //Not granted for permission
        }
    } else {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}

private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
    return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
}

private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                    return true;
                }
            });
}

private void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Utils class for checking multiple permission on android for READ and WRITE EXTERNAL PERMISSION

```
public abstract class PermissionUtil {

public static boolean verifyPermission(int[] grantResults){
    // At least one result must be checked.
    if (grantResults.length > 0){
        return false;
    }

    for (int results :grantResults){
        if (results != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Even I had provide permission for all in manifest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Add multiple permission into list.

**Method for checking multiple Permission**

```
public static final int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 101;

public static boolean checkAndRequestPermissions(final Activity context) {
    int ExtstorePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int cameraPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    if (cameraPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    }
    if (WExtstorePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded
                .add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context, listPermissionsNeeded
                .toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),
                REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Use it like,

```
if(checkAndRequestPermissions(MainActivity.this)){
    doWork();
}
```

and handle PermissionsResult like,

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case Utility.REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS:
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "FlagUp Requires Access to Camara.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                finish();
            } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Splash_Activity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "FlagUp Requires Access to Your Storage.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            } else {
                doWork();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Happy Coding..

Comment: Why did you pass final Activity context in method

Comment: @MerkyRobins because Context of Activity Required in some of code line. I passed Context in Method because i was using this method from different class. if you want to use this method in same class no need to pass context.

Comment: what is utility here ? @V-rundPuro-hit

Answer (score 1):

```
   private static final int PERMISSION_STORAGE = 1;

   if (Utils.checkForPermission(getActivity(), 
   Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) && 
   Utils.checkForPermission(getActivity(),  Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
      //do your work..
  }else {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{AUDIO_PERMISSION, MIC_PERMISSION}, PERMISSION_STORAGE);
                    }


        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        private void requestForPermissions(String permssion, int permissionCode) {
            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permssion)) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{permssion}, permissionCode);
            } else {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{permssion}, permissionCode);
            }
        }

     @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            switch (requestCode) {
                case PERMISSION_STORAGE:
                    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // do your work..
    }else{
    // show message that permission required.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    public static final int REQUEST_STORAGE = 101;

    String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    if (!hasPermissions(mContext, PERMISSIONS)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_STORAGE);
    } else {
       // TODo
    }
   }



     /*check permissions  for marshmallow*/
    @SuppressWarnings("BooleanMethodIsAlwaysInverted")
    private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

     /*get Permissions Result*/
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_STORAGE: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "PERMISSION_GRANTED");
                    writeFile();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "The app was not allowed to write to your storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```